# Java cant find specific key inside Hashmap

Tags: java

I want to find out if i already have an existing key in my Hashmap, but it doesn't work

**My code for main method**

```
HashMap<FamilyMember, LinkedList<FamilyMember>> map = new HashMap<FamilyMember, LinkedList<FamilyMember>>();

        map.put(new FamilyMember("Ac"),new LinkedList<FamilyMember>());
        map.put(new FamilyMember("Draku"),new LinkedList<FamilyMember>());


        if(map.containsKey("Ac")){
           System.out.println("Key is in the map");
        }else {
           System.out.println("Fail");
        }
```

**My code for constructor class**

```
package Graph;

public class FamilyMember {
    public String firstName;


    public FamilyMember(String fname){
        this.firstName = fname;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return firstName;
    }
}
```

When I run my code it returns "Fail". How can fix this, im going to use the generics and hashmap for my graph data structure.

Comment: The key is the FamilyMemeber object, not the String "Ac". So your FamilyMemeber object needs to implement the `equals(...)` method.

Comment: Your hashmap's key is of type `FamilyMember`, but inside `containsKey` you are passing a `String` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Map key type is `FamilyMember` so it will not find a search for a String (“ac”).

If you want to key to be a FamilyMember object, then you’ll need to override hashCode() and equals() in your FamilyMember class.  And when you search for an item in your HashMap, you’ll need to provide an instance of a FamilyMember object that has the same hashCode() (and returns true for the overridden equals() method.

In your case it could be as simple as

```
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return firstName.hashCode();
    }
        
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null) return false;
        if (this.getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        FamilyMember fm = (FamilyMember) o;
        return firstName == fm.firstName\;
    }
```

If you want to be able to look up a LinkedList by a String, you’ll need your HashMap to be HashMap<String,LinkedList>